# Google Analytics - How to find URL of the previous page in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, google-analytics

I am trying to distinguish where people are coming to my website on a specific page. So if they come from my list of set pages, I want to pass a different URL to Google Analytics. If the user directly types up the link, the previous page would not be amongst the et pages I have in my list. Hence those visits I will pass a different URL to GA.

I know how to pass pageviews in GA. My problem is, how do I get to know what page they were on beore. I tried using document.referrer, window.location.hostname, and all that jazz but nothing seems to work.

Need help soon, thanks!

Comment: "Nothing seems to work" is pretty vague. document.referrer (if set, not all browsers send it) is the previous page. So maybe your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: How can I print so I know if document.referrer is giving me the right URL or not?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with PHP only (or any other server-side language) generally. The referrer is sent with the HEAD request to the server, so, in PHP you would use

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']
```